# Displaying related child records on a single row

Tags: t-sql

in DBs I'm familiar with, a query listing parents and children would look like this:

Parfirst    ParLast    Childfirst
Mary        Smith      Sally
Mary        Smith      Jim
Mary        Smith      Kim

However, I've been asked to create a report that looks like this:

Parfirst    ParLast    Child1   Child2   Child3   Child4
Mary        Smith      Sally    Jim      Kim

I'm at a loss as to how to accomplish this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please be advised, that this is not a homework production site. It is expected to tell what you have already tried, and in how far it didn't work, then ask a detailed question. Just dumping your questionnaire and asking others to fill it out for you is considered rude. Follow [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My apologies. The query I'm working on runs to a couple of hundred lines and has been in production for 6 years - I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible in the question.   I'm certainly no SQL expert, but I've been working in that environment for several years, and have never been asked to produce output that goes against the relational model, in my opinion. Does tSQL even support this type of output? A few tips to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: thanks for the tip - this is my first post. I'll be clearer in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function (if you are using SQL Server 2017 or newer) or to do some ugly XML magic using [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT t.ParFirst, t.ParLast, LEFT(t.Children, Len(t.Children)-1) As Children
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT p.ParFirst, p.ParLast, 
            (
                SELECT c.ChildFirst + ',' AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Children c
                WHERE c.ParentId = p.ParentId
                ORDER BY c.ChildFirst
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) l
        FROM dbo.Parents p
    ) t

SELECT p.ParFirst, p.ParLast, STRING_ACC(c.ChildFirst, ',') as Children
FROM dbo.Parents p
LEFT JOIN dbo.Children c on c.ParentId = p.ParentId
GROUP BY p.ParFirst, p.ParLast
```

If you want to include every child name in it's own column, you must define these columns in your query and you won't be able to return any additional child, if there is more than the number of columns you defined. Use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like this:

```
select p.ParFirst, p.ParLast, c1.ChildFirst, c2.ChildFirst, c3.ChildFirst
from dbo.Parents p
outer apply ( select ChildFirst from (select ChildFirst, row_number() over  (order by ChildFirst) as rowNo from dbo.Children c where c.ParentId = p.ParentId) t1 where t1.rowNo = 1 )  c1
outer apply ( select ChildFirst from (select ChildFirst, row_number() over(order by ChildFirst) as rowNo from dbo.Children c where c.ParentId = p.ParentId) t2 where t2.rowNo = 2 )  c2
outer apply ( select ChildFirst from (select ChildFirst, row_number() over(order by ChildFirst) as rowNo from dbo.Children c where c.ParentId = p.ParentId) t3 where t3.rowNo = 3 )  c3
```

Comment: Thanks - Here's the test query I'm using - modified to suit my table and column names. Since I'm working in SQL 2008, I followed your first example.               SELECT t.First, t.Last, LEFT(t.Child, Len(t.Child)-1) As Child
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT p.First, p.Last, 
            (
                SELECT c.First + ',' AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Child c
                WHERE c.PID = p.ID
                ORDER BY c.First
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) Child
        FROM dbo.Parent p
    ) t

Comment: Thanks - Here's the test query I'm using. Since I'm working in SQL 2008, I followed your first example.          SELECT t.First, t.Last, LEFT(t.Child, Len(t.Child)-1) As Child
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT p.First, p.Last, 
            (
                SELECT c.First + ',' AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Child c
                WHERE c.PID = p.ID
                ORDER BY c.First
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) Child
        FROM dbo.Parent p
    ) t    However it outputs all the children's names in a single column, comma delimited, not in separate columns

Comment: OK, now I have a column with all the relevant children's names listed, comma delimited. What I need to do is list each name in a separate column. How can I iterate through the comma delimited list to extract the nth child's name?

Comment: The number of columns of your query must be known at compile time, i.e. it must be hardcoded in the query. So you can only list as many children as columns you have. Then you can write N subqueries to return 1st, 2nd, etc. child. OFFSET/FETCH clause is the easiest way, but your version is too old to support it. I will update my answer with a sample how to do this using ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Great - regarding the number of columns in the query, I'm filling 20 possible columns in the output, and a scan of the data indicates I'll never get that many child records.